# Bar with buttons under statusBar, UINavigationBar or UIToolBar?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am looking to add a bar with buttons (buttons to fire actions, not for navigation) under the statusBar and above a custom UIView. My question is, I am not sure if I should be using UINavigationBar and adding UIBarButtonItem or if I should be using UIToolBar (which says it is used at the bottom of the screen) again adding UIBarButtonItem for the button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would usually use a `UINavigationController` for this and set the `leftBarButtonItem` and `rightBarButtonItem` of the `navigationItem` property of the view controller for the custom UIView.

Using UIToolbar is probably not what you want since it has a double border at the top, and a less visible border at the bottom, which would look weird in a toolbar at the top of the interface.

Comment: Thank you, I have gone back to using UINavigationBar as you suggested, here is what I am doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878638/standalone-uinavigationbar