# Standalone UINavigationBar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am looking to create a bar with a couple of buttons at the top of the iPhone interface just under the statusBar, the controller is a simple UIViewController so this is a bar for buttons not for navigation. I have got things working but it feels a little clunky and I was wondering if I was doing it right and not missing any shortcuts.

- There is no action / selector: set yet as I am just setting this up.
- I will probably remove the NSArray convenience method and add an alloc/release.

Code:

```
- (void)loadView {
    // VIEW
    UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame];

    // NAV BAR
    UINavigationBar *tempNavigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    [tempNavigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    UIBarButtonItem *testButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"TEST" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:nil];

    UINavigationItem *navItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
    [navItem setLeftBarButtonItem:testButton];
    [testButton release];

    [tempNavigationBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:navItem]];
    [tempView addSubview:tempNavigationBar];
    [tempNavigationBar release];
    [navItem release];

    [self setView:tempView];
    [tempView release];
}
```

Comment: Any reason you aren't using Interface Builder? I think all this code could be done from IB.

Comment: To be truthful I usually would use interfaceBuilder, however this time round I was trying to do things programatically to hopefully gain a little better understanding of how things work. Particularly for a new user, although IB is very useful and powerful it does hide/abstract some things that are useful to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks alright to me. An alternative would be to do this in Interface Builder, but that's a completely different matter.

If you intend to support autorotation, you may have to add some more code to set autoresize masks for your navigation bar so it expands correctly. Actually, I would use Interface Builder for this, because I'm big on visualizing my autoresize masks.

Comment: Much appreciated, IB, usually I would (See comment on question) but this time I just wanted to get an understanding of doing it programatically.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the question repeats but why you don't preferred I.B.? As you don't need navigational functionality then you need to look into an alternate i.e. [UIToolBar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIToolbar_Class/Reference/Reference.html) comes to mind. its usage is same as navigation bar as you need to **setItems** with NSArray as you are doing.

I hope you will succeed in finding your proper solution.

Comment: My reasoning behind not using UIToolBar (as @mrueg kindly pointed out in a previous question) is that UIToolBar is designed to present a shaded edge along its top edge so its not visually pleasing when used at the top of the UI. UINavigationBar on the other hand has a shaded edge on the bottom which makes it visually look a lot cleaner when used at the top of the UI.